# HttpWebRequest WebException 401 in .net 2.0

Tags: c#-2.0

The following code works in .net 4.0, but in .net 2.0 I get WebException 401 (And sadly I have to use .net 2.0).

```
string url = @"mypath";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.GetResponse();
```

This code simply invokes the URL.
The last line throws the exception.

When I enter the url manually in a web browser it works.

Any ideas?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "GET";

Comment: I still get the same exception.